# How to get non-repeated elements in a list

Tags: python

I want non repeating elements in a list. Here it is.

```
A=[1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 1]
```

Required Output: `[3,5]`

`set()` gives `[1, 2, 3, 5]`

Please let me know to achieve this task.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `count()` method from the [list](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) object to get a count equal to 1:

```
>>> A=[1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 1]
>>> unique=[i for i in A if A.count(i)==1]
>>> unique
[3, 5]
```

Alternatively the [`Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class from the [collections](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#module-collections) module can be used:

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 1]

c = Counter(A)

print [key for key, count in c.iteritems() if count==1]
```

Comment: This works, but this iterates the list over and over... While the example is a small list with larger lists this becomes wasteful.

Comment: Yeah Counter does make sense.

Comment: Nice. Counter is the way to go. The list comprehension, however, is more pythonic (and faster) as: `[ k for k,v in c.items() if v==1 ]`

Comment: @skx2 Thanks skx2. `iteritems` would be even better.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Counter` and `defaultdict` from [`collections`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html):

```
from collections import defaultdict
from collections import Counter

A = [1 ,2 ,3 ,2 ,5, 1]
# create a mapping from each item to it's count
counter = Counter(A)

# now reverse the mapping by using a defaultdict for convenience
countmap = defaultdict(list)

for k, v in counter.iteritems():
    countmap[v].append(k)

# take all values that occurred once
print countmap[1] # [3, 5]
```

If you're interested in what the mappings are you can print them:

The `counter`:

```
Counter({1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 1, 5: 1})
```

The `countmap`:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: [3, 5], 2: [1, 2]})
```

To manually create the counter you can use this function:

```
def make_counter(lst):
    counter = dict()
    for item in lst:
        if item in counter:
            counter[item] += 1
        else:
            counter[item] = 1
    return counter

make_counter(A)
```

Output:

```
{1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 1, 5: 1}
```

Comment: Hi Reut,

I am not able to use (Counter): 
from collections import Counter

Because I am using it as a script in thirdparty software package called Abaqus.

Do you thik we can use enumerate() in place of counter..?

Comment: @learner123 I added the code to create a counter-like mapping.

Answer (score 1):

**Plain vanilla python, no imports needed:**

Use a set to collect all elements you find, remove them and move to other set if you find them again - this is faster by a marging then using count(..) as [Tanveer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29860750/7505395) proposes.

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 1]
found = set()
found_again = set()

for a in A:
    if a in found_again:
        continue
    if a in found:
        found.remove(a)
        found_again.add(a)
    else:
        found.add(a)

print(list(found))
```

Output:

```
[3,5]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from collections import Counter
from functools import reduce


# Initialize Variable
A = [1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 1]
```

---

```
# iterating style
result1 = [key for key, count in Counter(A).items() if count == 1]
```

---

```
# functional style
result2 = reduce(
    lambda acc, pair: acc + [pair[0] if pair[1] == 1 else acc,
    Counter(A).items(), [])
```

Answer (score 0):

l1=[1,23,1]
l2=[]
for i in l1:
if l1.count(i)==1:
l2.append(i)
print("The Single Elements List:",l2)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```py
new = [i for i in A if A.count(i) == 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 1]
def non_repeat(a):
    cop1=list(a)
    b=list(set(a))
    for x in b:
        cop1.remove(x)
    for x in cop1:
        b.remove(x)
    return b

#Usage:
non_repeat(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort and get current, previous and next element, compare and add to final list of unique none repeating values.

```
def find_non_repeating_nums(nums:[int]):
    nums.sort()
    non_repeating = list()
    
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        cnum = nums[i]
        
        try:
            pnum = nums[i-1]
        except IndexError:
            pnum = None

        try:
            nnum = nums[i+1]
        except IndexError:
            nnum = None

        if cnum not in(pnum, nnum):
            non_repeating.append(cnum)

    return non_repeating
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a combination of filter and count:

```
A = list(filter(lambda a: A.count(a) == 1))
```